# Avoiding new parameter substitution when doing $\exists$ elimination.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I am trying to understand natural deduction in first order logic, but am confused about the $\forall$ and $\exists$ elimination rules.

**My understanding:**

If we know $\forall x \phi$ then we can substitute all free occurrences of $x$ in $\phi$ with a term $x_0$ because irrespective of the value of $x$ it must be that $\phi[x_0 / x]$ holds.

If we know $\exists x \phi$ then for some value of $x$ it must be that $\phi$ holds. However, we do not know which value of $x$ makes $\phi$ hold. So we substitute $x_0$ as a generic value which cannot appear anywhere before in the proof (because we can't assume anything about $x_0$). Essentially, we are giving a name to something we know must exist, $x_0$.

**My Question:**

After seeing the quantifier equivalences below,

$$\neg\forall x \phi \dashv \vdash \exists x \neg \phi $$
$$\neg\exists x \phi \dashv \vdash \forall x \neg \phi $$

it seems as though we can avoid substituting a new parameter when doing $\exists$ elimination by converting $\exists x \phi$ to $\neg\forall x \neg\phi$ and applying $\forall$ elimination to it.

So using this conversion we could avoid going from $\exists x \phi$ to $\phi[c / x]$ where $c$ is a new parameter, by going from $\exists x \phi$ to $\neg\forall x \neg\phi$ to $\neg(\neg\phi[x_0 / x]) \equiv \phi[x_0 / x]$ for any term $x_0$.

How can this be allowed?

Comment: Correct: "So we use a **new** term $a$ which cannot appear anywhere before in the proof (because we can't assume anything about it). Essentially, we are giving the "name" $a$ to something we know must exist."

Comment: You cannot apply $\forall$-Elim to $\lnot \forall x \lnot \varphi$ because the rule applies **only** to a formula of form $\forall x \varphi$

Comment: Right so it's because of the outermost/leftmost $\neg$. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $\exists$-elimination is used when you have $\exists x \, \phi$ available as an assumption to prove something. For example in the proof $\exists x \, \phi \vdash \alpha$ you can use it to get $\phi[t / x] \vdash \alpha$ for some term $t$.

Indeed, you can instead use the equivalence to get $\neg \forall x \, \neg\phi \vdash \alpha$, but here the leftmost negation prevents you from using the $\forall$-elimination.

Comment: By the negation, you mean the outermost/leftmost negation right? @Lereau

Comment: @TomFinet yes indeed. I also changed it in the answer now; It's a good point to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Inference rules can only be applied to statements that have the relevant connective as its *main* connective.

This is why you cannot apply $\land \ Elim$ to a statement like $(P \land Q) \to R$ and hope to get $P \to R$ ... the main connective of $(P \land Q) \to R$ is the conditional, not the conjunction.   Good thing too, because $(P \land Q) \to R$ does not logically imply $P \to R$